# JavaFX. Доступ к объекту из другого класса

Tags: javafx

Мне нужен доступ к объекту primaryStage из другого класса, но не знаю как это сделать.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    primaryStage.setTitle("Mr.Presedent");

    Parent menuRoot = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("menuScene.fxml"));
    Parent firstRoot = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("firstScene.fxml"));


    Scene menuScene = new Scene(menuRoot, 600, 400);
    Scene firstScene = new Scene(firstRoot,600,400);



    primaryStage.setMinHeight(600);
    primaryStage.setMinWidth(400);
    primaryStage.setScene(menuScene);
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {launch(args);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить этот объект в контроллер, и вставить его при загрузке.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    String path = "/fxml/MainView.fxml";

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    Parent root = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource(path).openStream());

    RootController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
    controller.setStage(stage);

    ...

    stage.show();
    stage.toFront();
}
```

Это код из контроллера:

```
private Stage stage = null;

public void setStage(Stage stage) {
    this.stage = stage;
}
```

Ещё как вариант(не очень хороший) сделать публичную статическую переменную а записать в неё ссылку на нужный тебе объект.

```
public static Stage stage;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    String path = "/fxml/MainView.fxml";

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    Parent root = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource(path).openStream());

    ...

    stage.show();
    stage.toFront();
    MainRun.stage = stage;
}
```

Comment: Дополнительно бы добавил, что `RootController` в данном случае - название класса контроллера, которое может быть и любим другим. Это вроде и очевидно, но на первых порах можно упустить данный нюанс

Comment: Можно еще передать `FXMLLoader`'у самостоятельно созданный  объект контроллера через метод `setControllerFactory()`. И при создании этого объекта передать ему ссылку на `primaryStage`.

Answer (score 0):

*На заметку:* В контроллере можно получить ссылку на окно, в котором расположен элемент.
В зависимости от ситуации, это окно может оказаться primaryStage.

// в контроллере:

```
...
@FXML
private Label label123;
...
    // В каком-либо обработчике (но не в конструкторе, и не в initialize(),
    // так как к моменту их вызова сцена и окно, вероятно, еще не назначены):
    Stage stage = (Stage)(label123.getScene().getWindow());
```